# Search ID list and match in excel

Tags: excel, formula

I have a list of random emails and then a list of emails with IDs. I want to get the ID's from the list, to assign to my random list.

So

```
ID email                                ID  emails jumbled up
43 emailaddress1                         ?  emailaddress3
46 emailaddress2                         ?  emailaddress1
32 emailaddress3                         ?  emailaddress2
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`Index` & `Match` will work for this:

> D2 = INDEX(A:A,MATCH(E2,B:B,0),1)

Drag this equation down to your last Jumbled email to populate your IDs (in this example, down to D4). If your two tables are on separate sheets, you will need to adjust the equation accordingly.

[image]